# How to include list based on a condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, any

I have this code:

```
ClassroomList.Where(x => x.StudentList.Any(y => y.IsMale) == true);
```

this code returns `ClassroomList` only if all student in StudentList `IsMale == true` but returns none if there is at least 1 `IsMale == false`.

How do I always return ClassroomList that only includes those Students with `IsMale == true`.

Here is ClassroomList's Class:

```
public partial class ClassroomList
{
    public ClassroomList(){}
    public list<Student> StudentList {get; set;}
}
```

Here is Student Class:

```
public partial class Student 
{
    public Student (){}
    public bool IsMale {get; set;}
}
```

Here's a sample of the expected output

```
Classroomlist Count |  Studentlist Count |  Male | Female | 
         2                    5              3       2       
         2                    10             10      0
         2                    8              0       8
```

Expected output:

```
1. ClassroomList[1].Studentlist[2]
2. ClassroomList[1].Studentlist[9]
3. ClassroomList[1].Studentlist == null
```

Comment: @Desperado hi thanks I've checked it out, it throws an error saying cannot convert IEnumerable to Icollection. Is there no more need to use Any() or All() ?

Comment: Oh, the main error is "The entity or complex type ..cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: `StudentList = x.StudentList.Where(y => y.IsMale).ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inner where filter.

`ClassroomList.Where(x => x.StudentList.All(y => y.IsMale) )`;

Update:
So you need like this?

`ClassroomList.Select(x => new ClassroomList{
                     StudentList = x.StudentList.Where(y => y.IsMale).ToList()
                  }
)`;

Comment: Does this compile ?  `x.StudentList.Where(y => y.IsMale)` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: @user3185569 absolutely yes! Since StudentList is also an IEnumerable

Comment: Try it. It will not compile. Where expects a `Func<T, bool>` meaning a function that accepts `ClassroomList` as a parameter and returns a `boolean`. Your function `x.StudentList.Where(y => y.IsMale)` doesn't return a `boolean`. Just try it, you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: @user3185569 yes you are correct. `All` is the correct API thanks!

Comment: Hi I don't know if my question is wrong since all answers are common but it doesn't resolve my problem. Lets see, with the solutions given ClassroomList is only returned if all the Student in StudentList IsMale. ClassroomList should always have a value while StudentList will only have Males

Comment: @user3770093 is this the answer you want? so basically i will select all classroom list but for each student list in a classroom list, it should only contain males?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the edited expected output, you can use this:

```
 var results = (from r in ClassroomList
               let grp = r.StudentList.GroupBy(x => x.IsMale)
               select new
               {
                   ClassRoomsCount = ClassroomList.Count(),
                   StudentsCount = r.StudentList.Count,
                   Male = grp.Where(x => x.Key).Count(),
                   Female = grp.Where(x => !x.Key).Count()
               }).ToList();
```

**Side Note :** you can remove this line `public ClassroomList(){}` the compiler already creates a hidden default constructor, so no need to do it yourself.

Comment: Hi I don't know if my question is wrong since all answers are common but it doesn't resolve my problem. Lets see, with the solutions given ClassroomList is only returned if all the Student in StudentList IsMale. ClassroomList should always have a value while StudentList will only have Males.

Thanks for the tip too. I think Ill edit my question to add more details

Comment: @user3770093 not it is clear what you want. Check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are all most there, just use `All` extension.

```
ClassroomList.Where(x => x.StudentList.All(y => y.IsMale));
```

After you update the question, seems you need something like this.

```
var result = ClassroomList
                .Select(x=> new 
                 {
                     StudentListCount = x.StudentList.Count(),
                     MaleCount = x.StudentList.Count(c=>c.IsMale),
                     FemaleCount = x.StudentList.Count(c=>!c.IsMale),
                 };
```

Comment: You can always invalidate your vote if this is not answer to the question ;-)

Comment: I cannot revert it to 0, it will get downvoted instead :P. I know this is a correct answer also, but I also answered so I will defend my answer :)

Comment: Hi I don't know if my question is wrong since all answers are common but it doesn't resolve my problem. Lets see, with the solutions given ClassroomList is only returned if all the Student in StudentList IsMale. ClassroomList should always have a value while StudentList will only have Males

Comment: @user3770093 check the update, this should produce your desired output